# Spring Eureka Client Fail to register with Eureka

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

Java Version : 19
Spring Boot Version : 3.0.1
Spring Cloud Version: 2022.0.1

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field optionalArgs in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration required a bean of type 'com.netflix.discovery.AbstractDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.netflix.discovery.AbstractDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs' in your configuration.

Unable to run Eureka client services

Comment: Please provide your Eureka server and client application.properties files, Maven files, and the ApplicationStarter class here.